# how to update a state by calling a local function by return() in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React js. I want to update the value of state by calling the local function from, {this.UpdateValue(this.state.values)} function, then also want to check the value in if() statement. If condition satisfies(true) code will be continue, else first object1.map() function will be called again.

Like here, I am trying to update the value of the state from 0 to 1Please help me. Here is my code-

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class UserProfiles extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            values:0,
        }
    }
    UpdateValue(value){
        this.setState({values:value + 1});
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {object1.map((item, index)=>{
                    /*some operation*/
                    {this.UpdateValue(this.state.values)}

                    {object2.map((item, index)=>{
                        if(this.state.values === index){
                            / some operation /
                        }                   
                    })}

                })}
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Updating state from render will create the component to re-render which will in turn update state, again a re-render. There will be an infinite loop. Please read about event driven programming and when state should be updated

Comment: Thank you @AjayGaur for your valuable suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do this you will create infinite loop because every time you update state component re-renders itself, so instead you can use `ComponentDidMount` method.

```js
class UserProfiles extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      values:0,
    }
  }
  
  UpdateValue(value){
    this.setState({values: value + 1});
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.UpdateValue(this.state.values)
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.values}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserProfiles />,
  document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setState` from the render function will cause your component to go in an endless loop, since setState causes a `re-render` and `re-render` in turns causes a `setState` call, If you want to do it once after render, just add your function call in the `componentDidMount` function

```
UpdateValue(value){
    this.setState(prevState => {value: prevState.value + 1})
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.UpdateValue()
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.value}
        </div>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `this.UpdateValue` it's very likely to occur maximum call stack in your code since every `setState` triggers a new `render` in the component.

State changes usually happen upon user interactions, such as button click or text input change for example.

I recommend you read a bit more about [state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in ReactJS' docs.

```js
class UserProfiles extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      values: 0
    }

    this.UpdateValue = this.UpdateValue.bind(this)
  }

  UpdateValue() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      values: prevState.values + 1 
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{`Values: ${this.state.values}`}</div>
        <button onClick={this.UpdateValue}>Click-me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserProfiles />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Each time the button clicked value will inc

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
          values: 0
      }
  }
  
  updateValue = () => {
      this.setState({values: this.state.values + 1});
  }
  
  handleClick = () => {
    this.updateValue()
  }
  
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>{this.state.values}</div>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Button
          </button>
        </div>
      )
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    
</div>
```